# Is SASI index in Cassandra efficient for high cardinality columns?

Tags: cassandra

I understand Secondary Indexes in general are inefficient on high cardinality columns but since SASI is built from scratch I wonder if the same argument applies there? If not, Why? Because I believe primary keys in Cassandra are indeed indexed in a way and since Primary key is supposed to be the column with highest cardinality why not do the same for secondary indexes?

Comment: Could you please give an example query you're curious about? (point queries / range queries?) How many results you expect your queries return on average?